# 2D Cartesian Matrix / coordinate transformation.

Tags: geometry, matrices, transformation, coordinate-systems

I has initially asked this question in the programming site but did not get an answer that worked. This is my first question on this site so please bear with me.

Consider a page with three distinct markers for determining orientation. Top-Left, Top-Right and Bottom-Left. This page is fed into a scanner and the resulting image has been transformed in three ways namely rotation, scale and translation.

I know the original coordinates and the transformed coordinates and can measure the value of each transformation.

With a very basic mathematics background, I cannot figure out:

- In which order should the transformations be applied?
- In a computer program, transformations are applied one after the other so the known coordinates are rendered useless for subsequent transformations. Is there a way to normalize this through calculations?